# Increasing space between rows in table dynamically created from js function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a JS function in a modal that is creating a table in a grid from data being returned from a controller action. It works fine, however I wish there was a little more space between the rows. I have tried adding &nbsp and it doesn't seem to do the trick.

Can anyone give me a solution to this? Below is a picture of the modal, my JS function and the markup for the modal.

modal:

[image]

JS function:

```
  $("button[name='paramsBtn']").click(function () {
    /* Grabs ID from col selected */
    var $col = $(this).closest('.row').find('.requestId');
    var jobRequestId = $col.data('id');
    var nameType = $col.data('name');

     $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("JobPollerParameters", "Tools")',
         data: { "jobRequestId": jobRequestId, "name" : nameType},
         success: function (results) {

            $modal = $('#paramsModal');
             $modal.modal("show");

             var name = [];
             var value = [];

             var arr = results;  

             //loop through arr created from dictionary to grab key(s) and value(s)
             for (var key in arr) {
                 if (arr.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                     //name += key;
                     //value += results[key]; 
                     name.push(key);
                     value.push(results[key])

                     //Remove previous rows
                     $("div[name='params']").remove();
                     for (var i in name) {
                         //Adding parameters as rows 
                         $('<div class="col-md-6 text-break" name="params"> ' + name[i] + '</div>'+ '<div class="col-md-6 text-break" name="params">' + value[i] + '</div>').insertAfter($('#modalGridHeader'));
                     }

                 }

             }
        }
    });
});
```

markup for modal:

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="paramsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header modal-header-primary" style="margin-bottom:-16px;">
                        <a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary pull-right" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalTitleText">Job Parameters</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body" style="height:250px;">
                        <div class="list-group">
                            <div class="row list-group-item list-group-item-heading container divTableHeading" style="width:inherit; margin-bottom:0px;" id="modalGridHeader">
                                <div class="col-md-6 font-weight-bold"> Parameter(s): </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 font-weight-bold"> Value(s): </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The line that is adding the rows is:

```
 $('<div class="col-md-6 text-break" name="params"> ' + name[i] + '</div>'+ '<div class="col-md-6 text-break" name="params">' + value[i] + '</div>').insertAfter($('#modalGridHeader'));
```

Here is where I have tried adding &nbsp. I have also tried adding margin-bottom:5px, but it looked very odd.

Thanks

Comment: Why dont you use tables instead? Giving it a bootstrap class? You can also try adding a parent `div` for each pair of dynamic `col-md-6` elements and provide `row` class to the parent..

Comment: what's problem of adding "height" to your div?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao it's not an option. I was told not to.

Comment: Ok.. How about adding a parent `div` for each pair of dynamic `col-md-6` elements and provide `row` class to the parent?

Comment: @Alex-TinLe I can add height in the Jquery insertAfter(), but I was hoping to find a better way to solve this

Comment: You want your UI look better. So the best is to put a css class to the div, then style it with height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty

In `<div class="col-md-6 text-break" name="params">` add `style="height:20px;"`.